# jquery function "is not a function" inside same function confict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, moodle

I've included a toggle switch jquery library that is giving me "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).switchbutton is not a function" when the same is fired on checked. Please see code. I'm not sure why it would do this.

I've tried also a different library called bootstrap-toggle but same issue when triggering the same event on a different item after the even has finished.

```
$('.easyui-switchbutton').switchbutton({
    onChange: function(checked){
        console.log(checked);//works 
        $('#btnAll').switchbutton('uncheck');//this triggers error
    }
});
```

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).switchbutton is not a function

Comment: What's the HTML for both selectors?

Comment: Unfortunately, that code doesn't give enough to go by. Try reading this for details [mcve]

Comment: i didn't add the html because i didn't think it was relevant. I'm using the easyui library that converts inputs into switches:

Comment: <input class="easyui-switchbutton" id="btnAll" checked>
<input class="easyui-switchbutton" id="btnOne" >

Comment: Since you are unable to provide an example that we can use to duplicate your issue, all solutions provided are random guesses. For example did you wrap the entire thing in `document.ready` or `$(function($){`?

Comment: Have you tried a basic HTML page with just jquery, switchbutton and your implementation code?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple chances of this error.

- You're including your JS code before adding jquery library.
- element $('.easyui-switchbutton') may not be available in the
  document.

Have you tried this with simple HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

switch button is not a function in the JQuery object. You can add it:`$.fn.switchbutton = function(){code here}`
If this function comes from an external library make sure to include it.

Comment: I'm using the easyui library

Comment: If switchbutton comes from the easyui lib then it's included in the script incorrectly or after the event binding is done. Make sure the file is loaded before you wire up the switchbutton. Testing your code, and it works if you add the function to JQuery so verify that the script loads first. Let me know if that fixes that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Declare another function, put the error line in it and call the newly declared function inside the onChange event.

```
function uncheckAll()
    {
      $('#btnAll').switchbutton('uncheck');
    }



$('.easyui-switchbutton').switchbutton({
        onChange: function(checked){
           console.log(checked);//works 
           uncheckAll();
        }
    });
```